# Graphs with same degree sequence and same number of vertices isomorphic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness, graph-isomorphism

if there are two graph $G$ and $H$ that have same number of vertices, and their degree sequences are the same. Does this mean that they are isomorphic ?

Comment: Can you think of a counterexample with six vertices each?

Comment: no not really, because their degree sequences are the same, I think they match up the same and their structures are the same

Comment: There are two nonisomorphic graphs with 6 vertices, all of degree 2. Likewise, there are two nonisomorphic graphs (the complements of the ones mentioned before) with 6 vertices all of degree 3.

Answer (score 0):

Look up "graph isomorphism problem". You will find that it is a known hard problem. By contrast, computing the degree sequence is easy. So, by resorting to authority, the answer is "no". More specific reasons are in the comments.